# Limit Orika Custom Filter Scope to Class Map, rather than factory

Tags: java, orika

Given POJO's Foo and FooDTO, I would only like to map Foo.field if Foo.fieldCondition is not null (and matches various conditions). Currently I am achieving this by using a Custom Filter, where I do the code shown below. However since custom filters are registered with MapperFactory, they filter all fields regardless of the top level POJO class. For example filter will also run on Bar.barFiled, Sample.sampleField and etc. Can I limit filter scope by registering it to ClassMapBuilder ?

```
public class FooCustomFilter extends NullFilter<Object,Object> {

@Override
public <S , D > boolean shouldMap(final Type<S> sourceType, final String sourceName,
                                                    final S source, final Type<D> destType,
                                                    final String destName,
                                                    final MappingContext mappingContext) {


    Class clazz = mappingContext.getResolvedSourceType().getRawType();

    if (Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
    // validate object in context and return according to that
    return validate(...);
}
```

Comment: Did you consider a `CustomMapper`?